# Javascript/HTML - Passing function return variable into a hidden input value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've read heaps of posts about this and I'm still having issues with passing the return variable from my function to a hidden input value. The function is checking all radio buttons on the page (12 of them) and finding the one which is selected. It is either passing NULL or the javascript to screen.php. I have tested the checked() function and it works (used alert() to show the value). I've read heaps of posts on passing values to hidden inputs and none of those solutions have worked for me.

If you need to see more code, I can post it on pastebin.

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function checked()
    {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('radio');
        var valueSelected;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) valueSelected = inputs[i].value;
        }

        return valueSelected;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="index.php">KSM</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <form id="form_ready" method="post" action="../backend/screen.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="screenid" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="status" value="READY" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pickupid" id="pickupid" value="" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="READY" onclick="document.getElementById('pickupid').value = checked();">
        </form>
        <div id="search">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="tab1"><a href="index_tbl.php">Ordered</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="1" value="001" />
                        <label for="1"> <span>001</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="2" value="002" />
                        <label for="2"> <span>002</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="3" value="003" />
                        <label for="3"> <span>003</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="4" value="004" />
                        <label for="4"> <span>004</span> </label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="5" value="005" />
                        <label for="5"> <span>005</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="6" value="006" />
                        <label for="6"> <span>006</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="7" value="007" />
                        <label for="7"> <span>007</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="8" value="008" />
                        <label for="8"> <span>008</span> </label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="9" value="009" />
                        <label for="9"> <span>009</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="10" value="010" />
                        <label for="10"> <span>010</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="11" value="011" />
                        <label for="11"> <span>011</span> </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="pickup" id="12" value="012" />
                        <label for="12"> <span>012</span> </label>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There are no elements with the class `radio` ?

Comment: There are also no checkboxes.

Comment: They are there but I didn't post them. Do you want me to add that code?

Comment: It would be helpful since its part of the script that is not working.

Comment: You should break out of the loop when you find the checked element. Since only one element of a radio group can be checked, there's no point in continuing. You could also just use `return inputs[i].value;` right there.

Comment: What do you mean by it's passing the Javascript to screen.php? What Javascript is it passing?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `= checked` instead of `= checked()` in the `onclick`?

Comment: What I mean about pass the Javascript to screen.php is it will post "document.getElementById('pickupid').value = checked();" or "checked();" as the value. The function checked() works, I have tested it by using <a onclick="alert(checked());">TEST</a>.

Comment: Why not set document.getElementById('pickupid').value =  in the original script. You can set it to valueSelected and would work fine. That way all you have in your onclick is the function name. Makes for a smaller margin of error.

Comment: @McCormick32 Ok, I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @McCormick32 Tried that but it's still not setting the value. screen.php grabs the POST data and this is the output I am getting. 

string 'UPDATE tbl_orders SET status='READY', screen_id='1' WHERE pickup_id=''' (length=70)

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside `checked`, does it get triggered?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not going to bother changing that function because I know it works as is. I know it could of been coded better but its not a major project so I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: Who said anything about changing the function? I want to make sure that the function is being called. So set a breakpoint in the Javascript debugger.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry misunderstood what you meant. I will try that now.

Comment: @Barmar So I set a breakpoint and got this error back "TypeError: checked is not a function" even though its coded like onclick="checked();". Any ideas why it would be saying that?

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="checked"`? IDs automatically become global variables, and that will replace the function with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going on with the current code you have is you're submitting the form before the JS has time to execute your function and put the data into the hidden input. I wouldn't really suggest doing it in the way you're doing now, but here's a quick fix.

In your HTML change the form to this

```
    <form id="form_ready" method="post" action="../backend/screen.php" onsubmit="return checked()">
```

And in your JS change your checked function to:

```
function checked(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('radio');
    var valueSelected;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) valueSelected = inputs[i].value;
    }

    return (document.getElementById('pickupid').value = valueSelected);
}
```

Also, get rid of the onclick on that submit button.